# the return type of sort in list methods in python

Tags: python

I expected applying sort method to a list be again a list and could be used in the right of =, but it seems it does not behave so

In the following code,

```
a1 = [0, 1, 22, 3]
a2 = a1.sort()
a3 = a1
print(a1,a2,a3)
```

a2 is not a list, and is "<class 'NoneType'>"
a1 and a3 are as expected.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`sort` performs an in place sort. That is, it modifies the original list.

If you want to create a new list, use the `sorted` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted.